# How to prepare a file-set of Ubuntu to fit in a CD?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10

I already have Ubuntu 10.10 installed and also Windows 7. I want to use Ubuntu in VirtualBox. The ISO I downloaded from the Ubuntu site got corrupted and I could not install from the burned CD.

Is there a way to create the same ISO image from the installed Ubuntu?

Comment: Try the Startup disk creator

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu?

Comment: @Benny: Yes I installed it and it is working. But I want to create a bootable ISO set from it instead of downloading so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folllow this guide and all of the software you have installed now will be in this ISO image. I am using Remastersys. (Make sure you have terminal open)

1. Edit the open the sources.list by typing sudo gedit /etc/apt/spurces.list .
2. At the bottem add this code deb http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/repository karmic/ don't worry about the kamric part it means on the site that the line supports karmic or higher. ave it and go back to Terminal.
3. Update the sources by typing sudo apt-get update and then press enter. Once done type sudo apt-get install remastersys to install it.
4. Create the ISO file by typing sudo remastersys backup custom.iso and then press enter.
5. Wait untill Terminal says Success and Minimize Terminal.
6. The ISO image will be in home/remastersys/custon.iso if it's not there make sure you move it to your Home Folder. (If its not there try the /remastersys sub folder then custon.iso
7. To delete the Remastersys files and folder in the Terminal run sudo remastersys clean only if you want to remove it.

Hope that works.